# How to define proxy functions giving params tuple to complex functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I currently rewrite a lib from JavaScript to TypeScript and needs to define proxy functions. They should accept all types and amount of params give them to the origin function like this:

```
async function any(table: string, columns?: string[], conditions?: object): Promise<object[]>
async function any(table: string, conditions?: object): Promise<object[]>
async function any(queryFunction: object): Promise<object[]>

async function any(...params: any[]): Promise<object[]> {
    return Promise.resolve([])
}


async function one(table: string, columns?: string[], conditions?: object): Promise<object>
async function one(table: string, conditions?: object): Promise<object>
async function one(queryFunction: object): Promise<object>

async function one(...params: any[]): Promise<object> {
    return (await any(...params))[0]
}
```

But `tsc` give me the error `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`.

The solutions for the issue I found doesn't really fit in my use case. I don't want to handle all possible param variations in the body of the proxy function, because it would be a big overhead. Also I don't want to have a `...param: any[]` overloading definition in the first function, because the param variations should be strict.

So someone have an idea how to solve that kind of issue in a good way?

Thanks and Greetings.

Comment: What's the TS version? Seems to compile for me (4+)

Comment: You can use a union of rest tuples instead of overloads, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXjAJm) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention me with @jcalz if you reply, or else I won't be notified)

Comment: @Igor Loskutov: The TypeScript version I use is 4.8.3. As far as I see, it's the current one.

Comment: @jcalz: That kind of type definition looks new to me and in the first try's it seems to perfectly fit in my needs. Special thanks for your help. Will try it in all my use cases. :)

Comment: So shall I write up an answer, or should I wait to see if it works for you?

Comment: @jcalz Feel free to write an answer, it works pretty well in all my use cases. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in TypeScript are fairly limited in usefulness:

- You can call an overloaded function with a single statically-known call signature and that's it.  In your code example, you could call `any("abc", ["def"])` or `any("abc", {c: 0})` or `any({q: 1})`, but you can't call it with anything like a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its possible parameters.  This is suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107), but it has not been implemented.
- When you implement an overloaded function you generally widen the function parameters to make it easy on yourself, but then the compiler no longer keeps track of the particular ways the function could actually be called.  So inside of your implementation of `one()`, you've got `params` as type `any[]`.  The compiler doesn't know that it will *actually* be either `[string, string[]?, object?]` or `[string, object?] or` [object]`.  It's just` any[]`.  So you can't call` any(...params)`, because` any()`doesn't accept an argument list of type`any[]`. There's a suggestion to support keeping track of the call signatures inside the implementation at [microsoft/TypeScript#22609](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22609), but again, this is not implemented.

These two issues together make it tough to approach things the way you're doing.  If you really want to use overloads, you should probably just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error and move on, noting that this is not making your compilation quieter, not safer:

```
async function one(...params: any[]): Promise<object> {
  return (await any(...params as [string]))[0]; // no error now
}
```

---

A common use for overloads is that different call signatures can have different return types.  But in your case they all return  the *same* return type for a given function, and that suggests a different approach: write a single call signature that takes a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a *union of* [*tuples*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  It could look like this:

```
type MyParams =
  [table: string, columns?: string[], conditions?: object] |
  [table: string, conditions?: object] |
  [queryFunction: object]

async function any(...params: MyParams): Promise<object[]> {
  return Promise.resolve([])
}

async function one(...params: MyParams): Promise<object> {
  return (await any(...params))[0]
}
```

Here the `MyParams` type represents the union of possible ways of calling `any()` and `one()`.  Inside the implementation of `one()`, the compiler knows that `params` is the same exact type as the type passed to `any()`, so it lets you call it with no error.  And you can verify that calling `any()` and `one()` behaves very similarly to the overloaded version:

```
// 1/3 any(table: string, columns?: string[] | undefined, 
//   conditions?: object | undefined): Promise<object[]>
// 2/3 any(table: string, conditions?: object | undefined): Promise<object[]>
// 3/3 any(queryFunction: object): Promise<object[]>    
any("abc", ["def"]); // okay
any("abc", { c: 0 }); // okay
any({ q: 1 }); // okay

// 1/3 any(table: string, columns?: string[] | undefined, 
//   conditions?: object | undefined): Promise<object>
// 2/3 any(table: string, conditions?: object | undefined): Promise<object>
// 3/3 any(queryFunction: object): Promise<object>    
one("abc", ["def"]); // okay
one("abc", { c: 0 }); // okay
one({ q: 1 }); // okay
```

Indeed, when you look at the IntelliSense hints when you call `one()` or `any()`, you are actually shown multiple call signatures as if they were "genuine" overloads.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KLi5nh5T0XK6tPqlE2m4vlDQchDVmQ11Tdpw7BqQrfbnagioe1I6m0tbxt3y-AKEAAtAwKguCbzpjeuyylqOqPu+qivk+nqflSQp-u8nyAfaTouoID56qhH5BqGqZdNGSAAIyRgAzIc67shiFRjjiw5lI4y5IAIdAQDw2gQHQnLEruF6BNxvH8YJdDocqNKdG8VEAEz0YxRQbuiW6VKJ7G8pJrjSdqskml+vKKSwVF0Wp1zSCeMrnmSCqmRhTwvCw2wFAARAo8BeQYdheXxPBeQGEZUaIADWIDsJ5Mg+fIfkGLghiqMGSAQkE4UxlFMVxdIKXDKo1EZVlUY5dFsWUTGtEMbZTEcSxRhsROWlcUuPGGQJxkiXOe40gZwUyXJZoNMKxAqTZBQNZuvXcuJhEdVJ3VCSN36BON5VINZdUFPZZ6agta2YR5bwsglSU+kF-GhWVEWVV052+f5eCpUg6WZdldQPWd2oFUgRU0aVX25VV14ZdC+AQkAA)